# New state in automata?

Tags: automation, dfa, nfa

While converting NFA to DFA we sometimes have to make a new state in order to achieve it. What exactly is that new state?

Like, {q0, q1, q2} is a new state. Does it mean, in that state we can achieve q0 or q1 or q2...or what?

Answer (score 0):

yes,in NFA there are long way or not minimal way to execute string so, some times when you convert to DFA, some group of states ex{q0,q1,q2} are converted to one state so you can achive minimal automation.for ex. consider this NFA.

[image]

it will be converted to DFA like this.

[image]